# Datamosh Aviglitch commande : Undefined method `filter' for #<Array:0x00007fbb74861898> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm using ruby gem for video datamoshing for a while. But since re-installation of my OS, my datamosh commande doesn't work anymore. I try to search about this but don't understand what I need to do and where does it come from.

```
BP-de-geoffrey:~ geoffrey$ datamosh /Users/geoffrey/Downloads/IMG_4973.avi -o /Users/geoffrey/Downloads/IMG_4973TEST.avi

Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /usr/local/bin/datamosh:23:in `<main>'
    5: from /usr/local/bin/datamosh:23:in `load'
    4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.2.0/bin/datamosh:75:in `<top (required)>'
    3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.2.0/lib/aviglitch/base.rb:32:in `output'
    2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.2.0/lib/aviglitch/avi.rb:183:in `output'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.2.0/lib/aviglitch/avi.rb:379:in `search'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.2.0/lib/aviglitch/avi.rb:50:in `search': undefined method `filter' for #<Array:0x00007fbb74861898> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: [`Enumerable#filter`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter) was introduced in ruby 2.6 maybe just update your ruby?